# Qt getting nearby widgets of type around a widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to stack rectangular widgets one after another over a line edit and for each one, I need to know the position of the one to the left, so I can push the new one to the right, so they are next to each other instead of one over another. Is there a way to get a widget of the same type next to another widget, so I can check its coordinates and size and move the new one to the right respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are top-level widgets, there is. But if not, you'll need to tag them somehow and then search for them. Check for these function in `QApplication`:

```
QWidget *   topLevelAt(const QPoint & point)
QWidget *   topLevelAt(int x, int y)
QWidgetList topLevelWidgets()
```

and in `QObject` (from which `QWidget` inherits):

```
T   findChild(const QString & name = QString()) const
QList<T>    findChildren(const QString & name = QString()) const
QList<T>    findChildren(const QRegExp & regExp) const
```

Comment: what do you mean top-level widgets? they all have a QLineEdit as their parent, that puts them on an equal level?

Comment: top-level widget = widget with `parentWidget() == nullptr`. You need to use the second option then.

Comment: ok so I call findChild from the QLineEdit object, right? Since the small blocks are it's children.

Comment: you can do so, but the main thing is that you have a pointer or reference to the `QLineEdit` instance. You can then make the call from wherever you want.